# Can child daycare expenses be deducted on IL state taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, illinois

Can child daycare expenses be deducted on IL state taxes?

We're doing our own taxes and everything we've read has led us to believe that the answer is no, but just wanted to double-check to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Note you can get a *federal* tax credit though (either 20% or 35%) on expenses up to $3k for one child or $6k for more than one child.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that child *daycare* expenses are not deductible from Illinois income that is subject to Illinois income tax. Some *educational* expenses for K-12 schooling can be deducted on Schedule M, but not daycare expenses.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dilip! So it's as we expected. Bummer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alina Since my answer is satisfactory to you, please consider _accepting_ it by clicking on the check mark on the left, or at least _up-voting_ it by clicking the up arrow on the left of the question. Your question (and my answer) are repeatedly being shown on the list of questions that do not have any satisfactory (or any up-voted) answer as yet.

Comment: Is that the opposite of Federal?